# Why is PHP saying 6469 > 1,000,000?

Tags: php

Here's my PHP:

```
<?php

$a = $_FILES['profilepic']['size'];
if ($a>1000000){
    echo json_encode("larger than 1MB");
}
?>
```

All it's doing is grabbing the filesize of an upload and comparing it to 1,000,000. I am assuming 1,000,000 is also in bytes, hence it equals 1MB.

My issue is that a very small file, 6469 bytes, triggers the echo, meaning PHP sees 6469 > 1,000,000.

I have echoed $a directly and it returns 6469, I assume it is bytes because Windows says the file is also 6469 bytes.

What's going on? Here's the file: https://easyupload.io/9spcmh

Comment: don't assume value in byte print value of a and check how much its showing.

Comment: `6469 < 1000000` but `6469 > '1,000,000'`

Comment: Why is everyone assuming he's using `'1,000,000'` when his code says otherwise? @yosimba2000, can you `var_dump($a)` right before your check?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @Jeto NVM I just got it. If you use gettype($a), turns out for some weird ass reason, $a returns an array, where the actual number 6469 is in the 0th index of the array.

$a[0] >1000000 now resolves correctly, thanks all!

Comment: @yosimba2000 It might be an array when the form is uploading multiple files, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: It's only a single file upload. But yes, $a returned an array, even for a single file upload. $a[0] retrieves the number :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem is it actually compare

```
6469 > 1 // that is true in (6469 > 1,000,000?)
```

If you actually compare look like below not comma separator

```
6469 > 1000000
```

Comment: NVM I just got it. If you use gettype($a), turns out for some weird ass reason, $a returns an array, where the actual number 6469 is in the 0th index of the array.

$a[0] >1000000 now resolves correctly, thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

If you use gettype($a), turns out for some weird reason, $a returns an array, where the actual number 6469 is in the 0th index of the array. $a[0] >1000000 now resolves correctly, thanks all!